# local class incompatible in storm

Tags: apache-storm

I have an old topology that running a while. But recently, I need update this topology and thus killed it. When I trying to submit the updated topology to storm, such exception occurred:

`java.io.InvalidClassException: com.weibo.security.storm.bolt.IpCountBolt; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5336119852024782309, local class serialVersionUID = -572783398581060861`

So, I killed the storm process and tried to delete everything related to storm, including `storm.log.dir`, `storm.local.dir`, the entire node `/storm` in zookeeper and the entire `/tmp` directory. However, when I started the storm and submit the topology again, this Exception is still there.

I managed to bypass them by changing the class name in my topology, but this should not be the right solution.

I understand how it will cause InvalidClassException. But I believe I removed all the data related to the old topology. Why is still there? Is there anywhere else I missed that might hide cache for old topology?

Comment: Check to see (1) does the source for the class even define the serial version value (it chooses a random one if not) and (2) is it possible you're picking up a newer version of the class somewhere?

Comment: (1) no, it used a random value by default. (2) what do you mean by "picking up" a newer version of the class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with default values for serialVersionID.  If you don't declare a value for serialVersionID variable then the JVM will come up with a random one.  If you have storm running across to JVM's then each one will come up with it's own value.  That causes problems when you deserialize the bolt on a different JVM that it was serialized as the serialVersionID of the deserialized object has to match the serialVersionID of the class in the local jvm.

To solve, try to define the variable for that class.  If you don't have the source, then you'll have to create a subclass with serialVersionID declared..

Comment: In my understanding, your answer means that the topology would fail at the beginning, because the serialVersionID is different between JVMs. But it not. It works well when I first time run it and failed until I try to change the bolts and run it again.